# Как убрать PAGEN_1 из пагинации в каталоге товаров Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, пагинация

Как убрать PAGEN_1 из пагинации в каталоге товаров Битрикс? Возможно кто-то уже такое реализовывал?

Есть сайт на Битрикс со стандартным каталогом товаров.
Сеошники требуют сделать изменить ЧПУ пагинацию в разделах каталога товаров!
Сейчас в разделе каталога такая картина
stoshin62.ru/catalog/legkogruzovye/?PAGEN_1=3
где PAGEN_1=3 - где 3 это 3-й лист списка товаров в разделе Легкогрузовые шины
Шаблон ссылки такой
stoshin62.ru/catalog<раздел>/?PAGEN_1=3

Сеошники хотят чтобы было так
stoshin62.ru/catalog<раздел>/3
Где 3 это третий лист в пагинации и не должно быть указано переменной PAGEN_1 в браузерной строке.

Как это можно реализовать? Задать новый паттерн для обработки адресов в файле urlrewrite.php? 
Пробовал по blog.d-it.ru/dev/84 но не заработало.

Comment: Пробовал, но не заработало, хорошая фраза. Способов реализации два. Первый - писать свой обработчик адресов для пагинации. Второй - менять компонент навигации. Второй ненадежен так как битрикс в любой момент может что-то поменять в АПИ и все пойдет насмарку.